# php admin and user account doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a login form. I have in my table of the database two records: admin and user. If you login if admin you must go to admin_area.php. this is not working, he always log in if user.
If you login if user this works.
The first part of the script is not working and don't run.

Can someone help me?
thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//first part: this is not working
session_start();
//if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$a_username = $_POST ['username'];
$a_password = md5( $_POST ['password']);

if($a_username == "admin" && $a_password=="intel")
{
    include 'connect.php';
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$a_username' AND password='$a_password' ";

    $numrows = mysqli_query($link, $sqli)    or    die(mysqli_error());

        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';

        //Add some stripslashes
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);

        //Check if username and password is good, if it is it will start session
        if ($username == $a_username && $password == $a_password)
        {

            $_SESSION['username'] = 'true';
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            //Redirect to admin page
            header("Location: admin_area.php");exit();
        }

}

//second part: this works
$username = $_POST ['username'];
$password = md5( $_POST ['password']);

if($username&&$password)
{
include 'connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";

$numrows = mysqli_query($link, $query)    or    die(mysqli_error());

if ($numrows != 0)
{
    /
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($numrows))
    {
        $dbusername  = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword  = $row['password'];
    }

        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        {
            echo "you are log in <a href='user.php'>click here for contine</a>, after 4 seconds"; header('Refresh: 4;url=user.php'); 
            $_SESSION ['username'] = $username;
        }
        else
         echo "<h3>incorrect password,  <a href='index.php'>click here</a></h3>";

}
else 
    die ("text");



}

else 
    die ("text");
//}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use MD5 for password hashing. [It's insecure](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). Consider `password_hash` instead

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: *I fear we're wasting our breaths/words here gentlemen..., and possibly "ladies".*

Answer (score 1):

```
$a_password = md5( $_POST ['password']);

if($a_username == "admin" && $a_password=="intel")
```

This condition is not valid, because

```
$a_password = md5( $_POST ['password'])
```

is first converted to md5 format and then checked `$a_password=="intel"`
`$a_password` is now in md5 format and `intel` is normal string. For this first try to match normal `$a_password` like

```
$a_password = $_POST ['password']
```

and write your variable into your condition as like

```
$a_password = md5( $_POST ['password'])
```